# I cant get a display the 3rd console log in my code

Tags: javascript

I cant get a display the 3rd console log in my code as the title says im kinda stuck I know this happens because the loop is not run async so the code does not have time to be executed before the method is done
await on the loop does nothing
any suggetions or fixes?

```
let Order = new Orders();

let failed = false;

await req.body.productIDs.forEach(async ID => {
    console.log("dip");
    let product = await Fetcher.GetProductByID(ID);
    console.log('dap');
    if(!product || !product.isActive) failed = true;
    else {
        let prod = { 
            _id: product._id,
            Name: product.Name,
            Image: product.Image,
            Price: product.Price
        }

        Order.Products.push(prod);
        Order.TotalPrice = Order.TotalPrice + product.Price;
    }
});
console.log('døb');
```

my console spits out

dip

døb

missing the dap

Comment: `.forEach()` does not work with `async` callback functions. It ignores all return values from callbacks.

Comment: so using a for loop indstead and remove the async would work indstead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide the code for the `GetProductByID` function, which is quite important.

I've implemented it in two different ways. In the first, `GetProductByID` returns normally. In the second, `GetProductByID` returns an unresolved promise. In the second, I see the console.log result that you are seeing. [Note that the foreach calls the async function for each of the values regardless - it doesn't wait for anything in either case]

```
let req={body:{productIDs:[1,2,3]}};
let Fetcher = {GetProductByID: async function(x){return;}}

await req.body.productIDs.forEach(async ID => {
    console.log("dip");
    let product = await Fetcher.GetProductByID(ID);
    console.log('dap');
});
console.log('døb');




let req={body:{productIDs:[1,2,3]}};
let Fetcher = {GetProductByID: async function(x){return new Promise(()=>{});}}

await req.body.productIDs.forEach(async ID => {
    console.log("dip");
    let product = await Fetcher.GetProductByID(ID);
    console.log('dap'); // <= This never happens, because the promise doesn't resolve
});
console.log('døb');
```